# ld: 871 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7, clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I am using FastPDFKit in my iPhone app for displaying PDF. When I run the project on simulator, it works fine. However when I run the project on iPhone, it gives me below error.

```
duplicate symbol _value_map in:
    /Users/alkandari/Desktop/iPhone Apps/MyTest002/MyTest002/FastPdfKit.embeddedframework/FastPdfKit.framework/FastPdfKit(FastPdfKit)
duplicate symbol _writeUnicodeToUTF8Buffer in:
    /Users/alkandari/Desktop/iPhone Apps/MyTest002/MyTest002/FastPdfKit.embeddedframework/FastPdfKit.framework/FastPdfKit(FastPdfKit)
ld: 871 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ld: 871 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7


clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea why it is happening like this?

---

Error comes when I add FastPDFFramework in Configuration in Debug and Release section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can you try to clean up the FastPdfKit target and recompile it? It should generate a new framework ex-novo that you then should be able to add to you project, overwriting the one you are using. You can grab the new .embeddedframework in the FastPdfKit project root directory.**

These line helped me from the link below.

http://support.fastpdfkit.com/discussions/problems/759-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-armv7

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution I found even after messing with the header/framework search paths, rebuilding, etc:

http://support.fastpdfkit.com/discussions/problems/443-i-am-unable-to-link-fastpdfkitembeddedframework

I removed the **-all_load linker flag** in my project and it compiled successfully. As a warning, make sure removing this flag is appropriate for your project. It was probably placed there for a reason

Answer (score 2):

there are another reason this error often happens is accidentally importing the .m file instead of the .h.

it's happened to me :)

[link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279622/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-i386-clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279622/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-i386-clang)

Answer (score 1):

You have too many #include or #import directives in header files for the same things.  Move to using @class in headers and only import/include in your .m files.

In all you just need to review where these are and reassess them.

Comment: I don't have many include files. I just have `#import <FastPdfKit/FastPdfKit.h>` in view controller...

Comment: and if I have too many include why problem is not with simulator? why with iphone only?

Comment: Did you move anything ? So what this says to me is that something has been built already and is being rebuilt ( failing ). This something seems to be class extension. But googling for you I can see this on fastpdfkit support forum. http://support.fastpdfkit.com/discussions/problems/759-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-armv7

Answer (score 0):

I add my solution, as if you follow the readme, it will ask you to do:

```
Inherit the project options: select the Project an from info tab and configurations line choose **FastPdfKitFramework** from the drop down list;
```

I replace the FastPdfKitFramework target to None and now it work great.

As it is on the readme file, I never add .a in my project so download the recompile one don't help me as I do not want to restart all integration.
I hope it can be helpful for someone.

Answer (score -2):

I tries removing `-all_loads` linker flag, and it worked for me without any problem in the project.