# Xcode, 1 duplicate symbol for architecture armv7 , -ObjC, ZooZ

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, armv7, zooz

I am trying to integrate ZOOZ In App payment but it is giving me errors.
When i add flag -ObjC to **Other Linker Flags** , i get exception:

```
1 duplicate symbol for architecture armv7
```

If i dont add flag -ObjC to **Other Linker Flags**, i get another exception:

```
Unknown class ZooZCardViewController in Interface Builder file.
Unknown class ZooZButton in Interface Builder file.
Unknown class ZooZFooterPanel in Interface Builder file.
Unknown class ZooZSpinner in Interface Builder file.
Unknown class ZooZBasePanel in Interface Builder file.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [duplicate symbols for architecture armv7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427024/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

Comment: See these if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522902/error-ld-1-duplicate-symbol-for-architecture-armv7 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427024/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-armv7

Comment: i dont have extra duplicate
classes.