# Linker error with Facebook SDK v3.12

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, google-plus, linker-errors

I'm trying add a few social networks skds to my project. I've started from Facebook SDK and all works fine. But when I added a google+ sdk and added `-ObjC` flag, compile start failing with next error:

```
/Users/developer/Documents/Projects/iOS/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Facebook.o)
ld: 49 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But when I remove this flag, compile going good. What should I do in this situation?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427024/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

Answer (score 0):

if some framework or lib required flags (-all_Load or -ObjC) you can load this special libs with **Other Linker Flag** like this one

```
-force_load "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libRestKit.a"
```

don't remember exclude this lib from target to avoid symbol duplication