# duplicate symbols for architecture armv7 Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I have an old class "Approval.swift" in my swift project

I added NSManagedObject (Approval) in Core Data and i create NSManagedObject subclass with the same name (Approval.swift) for that entity

Then i changed the Entity name to "ApprovalObject" and the associated class to ApprovalObject.swift to differentiate it from the old class "Approval.swift"

When i tried to run the project, i got this error

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Card in:
>       /Users/MyUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-czluntwgoefegbeilusmojsyejlc/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ApprovalObject.o
>       /Users/MyUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-czluntwgoefegbeilusmojsyejlc/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Card.o
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Card in:
>       /Users/MyUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-czluntwgoefegbeilusmojsyejlc/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ApprovalObject.o
>       /Users/MyUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-czluntwgoefegbeilusmojsyejlc/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Card.o
>
> ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Can someone help me in solving this error?
Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you have added something twice. check once i mean `ApprovalObject`

Comment: @BuntyMadan thanks a lot! yes i checked ApprovalObject there was a mistake

Comment: cool, it happens! Enjoy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [duplicate symbols for architecture armv7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427024/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

Comment: asked many many times. Please search SO for existing answers prior to posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Duplicate symbols for architecture` mainly reason is you have added the same `.m` or `.o` file twice into your project. For resolving the issue just check the linker error like in your case its showing `ApprovalObject`. Then just go `build phases` then `compile sources` and search the specified file.

Answer (score 28):

I was getting the same type of error with a newly created app under Xcode 8. After much investigation I found reference to entries under Build Phases -> Compile Sources where I found that the data model was included in addition to the .m files. Removing this cleared the error and the app now builds and functions correctly.

Comment: Splendid! All other answers kept mentioning to look for duplicated .m files, you pointed out the data model file. I wasted 3 hours looking for the ghost .m file.

Comment: Shitfire.  What kind of QC at Apple let's this crap get through?  Thx for this answer, it marked an end to 2 hours of wasted time.

Comment: You are a genus!!! after hours of searching, finally sovled my problem!!! Other answers are making non sense, your answer is right!!!

Comment: Cant thank you enough. I wasted 4 hours looking for an answer.Thank you.

Comment: Thanks you save my day!

Answer (score 0):

I got the above build error because I imported a .m file instead of a .h file in another .m file