# duplicate symbols for architecture armv7 in two static libraries

Tags: c++, objective-c, iphone, cardreader

Two static libraries (iMagPay and chinese-dukpt) used here to read card data. And I faced issue of duplicate symbols.

[imagpay](https://github.com/subasa1985/sreader/tree/master/iMagPay.framework) & [chinese-dukpt](https://github.com/camcima/chinese-dukpt/tree/master/iOS/TestCardAnaly)

Both static library uses C++ code as well.

I used `-all_load` linker flag also, still see this error.

[image]

Comment: So what is your question then?

Comment: how to solve this error !!!!!

Comment: I see only one solution. Ask Static library developer to change naming convention of methods and variables name.  Anyone knows other thing apart from this !!!

Comment: Have you tried to use `objcopy`, just like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6940389/3214670?

Comment: did you find any solution? please post your answer. & i want latest iMagPay framework, from where i can get it?

Comment: Yes, remove any of above.
i removed chinese dukpt library. because no longer required.
For framework, you should ask that manufacturer.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check out [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427024/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-armv7?rq=1) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906147/what-does-the-all-load-linker-flag-do)?

This happens when you link libraries 'too broadly' i.e link stuff you don't need. If you don't need a library, don't link it.