# xcode 5 ld: 11 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors

When trying to build my project, I constantly get this error saying `ld: 11 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`
I recently tried to implement GPUImage to my project, would that have anything to do with it?
Also I read similar problems but none had my solution.

Comment: No one can help unless to provide more specific details about the linker errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had implemented my .m file from another view controller and in that view controller I implemented the first view controller, so it was like a loop.

Thanks for your answer though Gabriele, it helped me to find the loop.

Answer (score 8):

Wild guess, have you maybe imported a `.m` file instead of the `.h` anywhere?

Comment: Again ... your wild guess just save me some serious headache's too.  I'd upvote you more if it were possible.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

there are another reason this error often happens is accidentally importing the .m file instead of the .h.

it's happened to me

[link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279622/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-i386-clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279622/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-i386-clang)