# Getting Linker Errors since I tried to implement a new m-file

Tags: ios, linker

I just started working with xCode and Objective C.

I created a project with an storyboard and implemented my entire program into the view-Controller. I wanted to put some of this code now into a different m-file wich I simply include and call methods from my new m-file in the view controller.

My problem is that I get not linker-errors every time I try to build it.

The error code is

> 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What could cause this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [xcode 5 ld: 11 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553067/xcode-5-ld-11-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-clang-error-linker-com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is due to you have a duplicate symbol somewhere. Check this link this will helpful for you

http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/115858-apple-mach-o-linker-error.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple .m files for one .h file. You need to either:

1. Keep all the code in the original .m file.
2. Create a new class with it's own .h file.
3. Create a category for the original class.
           (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)

Make sure you only have one @interface and one @implementation declaration for each class.

Comment: I made an entirely new m-file with its own h-file ;) I never though people would even create multiple m-files for one h-file^^

Comment: Make sure then that you haven't accidentally copied over the name of the cold class in your @interface/@implementation declarations.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.

I happened to implement the same variable as global in two m-files.