# Apple Match-O Liker Error Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, google-drive-api

Good day! I'm recently Doing an app that needs to be connected to Google Drive, Now i followed these instructions, https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart. Now I'm having an error building the Project. This is the Error message,

```
Ld /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.app/ECOSIGNATURE normal i386
    cd /Users/ogcpaslevis/Desktop/ECOSIGNATURE
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/ECOSIGNATURE.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -all_load -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/ECOSIGNATURE_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.app/ECOSIGNATURE

duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.completionBlock_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.delegate_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.finishedSelector_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.signIn_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.savedCookiePolicy_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.webView_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.backButton_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.forwardButton_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.initialActivityIndicator_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.navButtonsView_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.rightBarButtonItem_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.request_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.systemCookies_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.signInCookies_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.popViewBlock_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.keychainItemName_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.initialHTMLString_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.browserCookiesURL_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.userData_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.properties_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.didDismissSelf_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.hasNotifiedWebViewStartedLoading_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.hasCalledFinished_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.hasDoneFinalRedirect_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.mustShowActivityIndicator_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2CookiesWillSwapOut in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.isViewShown_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.didViewAppear_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2CookiesDidSwapIn in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.keychainItemAccessibility_ in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2KeychainErrorDomain in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2Keychain in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMOAuth2Keychain in:
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Intermediates/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECOSIGNATURE.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
    /Users/ogcpaslevis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECOSIGNATURE-axdjydxlfmeraobatbkzaysdroun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
ld: 35 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can i fix this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps:

Check Build phases in Target settings.
Check if any file exists twice or once.
If file exist twice delete one. If not delete file in the bottom which is the latest one.
Build again.

From: [duplicate symbols for architecture i386 clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279622/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-i386-clang)

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind the error can be that you have implemented `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch` twice.

Probably, you have mistakenly imported `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.m` file in YourClass.m or YourClass.h file instead of `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h`